# Linux sshd suddenly began prompting for "Windows Authentication" from Cygwin ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin

I returned from vacation to find a "helpful" intern had installed some Mandriva 2011.0 updates on a linux server, and he had updated Cygwin to 1.7.16 on a Windows XP machine.

Prior to the updates, I could ssh from cygwin to the linux box using something like `ssh user@johnny5` and I could login using my Linux user/pass.  (sshd is configured for RSA public key authentication using local credentials.)

Now, when I attempt to login as before, I get:

`$ ssh user@johnny5`

`Windows Authentication`

`Password:`

`Domain:`

Nothing appears to have changed in `sshd_config`, so I have no clue as to what broke my usual login method.  (I'm tentatively blaming something on the Linux side - but I suppose it could have been the Cygwin update).

Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: Make the intern fix it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah, that was my first thought.  (Didn't work) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell ssh to go verbose and force the authentication method.  E.g.,

```
ssh -v -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@johnny5
```

The verbosity might tell you what's causing the problem.  You may have to disable another method of authentication with another -o

Comment: As much as I want to blame the intern, it looks like there was some shuffling of IP addresses.  My /etc/hosts entry for johnny5 no longer pointed to my Linux box.  Instead the IP address had been changed to actually point to a Windows box running sshd.  I hadn't considered that IT may have been the culprit.  This answer spurred me in the right direction.  Thanks!